# Cakephp Mongodb MongoUpdateBatch error

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

following is code sample and I am getting error "Current primary does not have a Write API support"

Please help

CODE :

```
$m = new MongoClient();
   $db = $m->selectDB('database_name');
   $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'collection_name');
   $batch = new MongoUpdateBatch($collection);
```

When I debug $collection it gives :

```
object(MongoCollection) {
    w => (int) 1
    wtimeout => (int) 10000
}
```

I think I want it to be w => (int) 0 as there are three write concerns (0, 1, 2). I guess the above code will run if write concern is 0.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php

Please help how to do it.

I have tried following code still the same error

```
$m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('database_name');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'collection_name');
    $collection->setWriteConcern(0);
    debug($collection); 

    $batch = new MongoUpdateBatch($collection, array("w"=>0));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply update MongoDB to version > 2.5. and your MongoDB PHP to version > 1.5.0**

I updated MongoDB to version 2.6.10. It helped to fix the problem.